# How to install libapache2-modxslt on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu, symfony1

I'm attempting to deploy a symphony application on ubuntu 12.04 LTS and am having problems installing libapache2-modxslt. Here is the output from check_configuration.php, as you can see XSL module is not installed.

```
********************************
*                              *
*  symfony requirements check  *
*                              *
********************************    
php.ini used by PHP: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini    

** Mandatory requirements **    
  OK        PHP version is at least 5.2.4 (5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2)

** Optional checks **    
  OK        PDO is installed
  OK        PDO has some drivers installed: mysql
  OK        PHP-XML module is installed
[[WARNING]] XSL module is installed: FAILED
            *** Install and enable the XSL module (recommended for Propel) ***
  OK        The token_get_all() function is available
  OK        The mb_strlen() function is available
  OK        The iconv() function is available
  OK        The utf8_decode() is available
  OK        The posix_isatty() is available
[[WARNING]] A PHP accelerator is installed: FAILED
            *** Install a PHP accelerator like APC (highly recommended) ***
[[WARNING]] php.ini has short_open_tag set to off: FAILED
            *** Set it to off in php.ini ***
  OK        php.ini has magic_quotes_gpc set to off
  OK        php.ini has register_globals set to off
  OK        php.ini has session.auto_start set to off
  OK        PHP version is not 5.2.9
```

I've type the following command in attempt to install libapache2-modxslt and this is what the output is.

```
mark@ubuntu:/$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-modxslt php5-xsl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-modxslt
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian/Ubuntu packages are named slightly different. It should rather be `libapache2-mod-xslt` not `libapache2-modxslt` (note the dash between "mod" and module name). So try

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-xslt php5-xsl
```

**BUT**, since you need XLS package for PHP only, then simply let the package manager find right dependencies itself (package management is well done and powerful on Debian and derivatives as Ubuntu). So simply do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-xsl
```

and let the things roll. If you are curious, you can always list package dependencies using i.e. `apt-cache` like this:

```
sudo apt-cache depends php5-xsl
```

but if not, and package you are going to install would need something additional, `apt` will let you know and ask for confirmation to install additional required packages.